# How to cancel execution of a long-running async task in a C# Winforms app

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, return, goto

I'm a quite inexperienced c# programmer and need help on managing the flow of my program. It is a WinFormApp that asks for multiple user inputs and then uses them to establish serial communication with a device in order to make measurements. The measurements are made in an async method that takes about 20 minutes to run. So I'm using

```
    void main()
    {
        //Setup
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await measurements();
        //Plot results
    }

    private async Task measurements()
    {
        while(true){
        //Make some measurements
        await Task.Delay(120000);
        //Make measurements, present data in the UI form.
        //return if done
        }
    }
```

Now I need to make a button which enables the user to cancel the measurements in order to change some input or parameter and then restart the measurements. So I added a "Cancel"-button.

```
    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox64.Enabled = true;
        button6.Enabled = true;
        button5.Enabled = true;
        textBox63.Enabled = true;
        button3.Enabled = true;
        trackBar1.Enabled = true;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        button7.Enabled = false;
        clearData();
        // measurement.Stop();            
    }
```

Now I do not know how to manage the flow of the program. I have tried to make a `try-catch` structure in `button1_Click()` and throw an Exception from `button7_Click`, but it doesn't get through to `button1_Click()`.
Then I tried to run `measurements()` on a new thread. But the thread does not have access to 70-ish UI items on my main form.
And even I wont sink as low as trying Goto.

What I need is advice on how you would program in this situation in order to get a good control of the application and not compromise the flow of the program with risky stuff like exceptions and Goto.

Comment: change your `while(true)` loop to `while(measuring)` and set `measuring=false` when it should stop

Comment: Also read up on Exceptions - what they are for, how they work & why they are not "risky stuff".

Comment: AntiHeadShot: Thanks, I thought about this, but it takes time, because each loop iteration takes so much time. I want the UI to respond quite quickly to actions of the user.



PaulF 9: Yes, I'm aware that exceptions are fine, but they shouldn't be allowed to control program flow. That was what I meant! :)

Comment: @NoobPointerException That is incorrect. Exceptions are for signalling exceptional control flow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to cancel the actual task midway through then you need to look at using a CancellationTokenSource and passing a cancellation token into your async method.

[This is the Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155759.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on that which has a good example near the bottom and [this is another good blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis.aspx) on showing a progress bar and allowing cancellation.  that second article has a good overview:

> Cancellation is controlled by the CancellationToken structure. You
>   expose cancellation tokens in the signature of cancelable async
>   methods, enabling them to be shared between the task and caller. In
>   the most common case, cancellation follows this flow:
>
> 1. The caller creates a CancellationTokenSource object.
> 2. The caller calls a cancelable async API, and passes the
>      CancellationToken from the CancellationTokenSource
>      (CancellationTokenSource.Token).
> 3. The caller requests cancellation using the CancellationTokenSource
>      object (CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()).
> 4. The task acknowledges the cancellation and cancels itself, typically
>      using the CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested method.

To make your app respond quickly to a cancel request you need to then check the cancellation token regularly in your long running method and respond to it accordingly if a cancellation has been requested.

Comment: I got it to work pretty well now, but had to create a structure looking like;

                                            for (int wait = 0; wait < 120; wait++)
                                        {
                                            await Task.Delay(1000);
                                            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                                        }

Answer (score 2):

This is some rough code, but it should do the trick.

Using CancellationToken.
I've used a toggle method to test if the async task is to be cancelled.

```
CancellationTokenSource cts;

private async button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    toggleAsyncTask(false)
}

private void toggleAsyncTask(bool isCancelled)
{
    if(cts==null)
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    if(!isCancelled)
    {
        await measurements(cts.Token);
    }
    else
    {
        cts.Cancel();
        cts.Dispose();
        cts = null;
    }
}

private async Task measurementsOne(CancellationToken token)
{
    try
    {
        while(true){
            //Make some measurements
            await Task.Delay(120000); // don't know if you need this.
            //Make measurements, present data in the UI form.
            //return if done
    }
    catch(OperationCancelledException)
    {
        // to do if you please.
    }
}

private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // button stuff
    toggleAsyncTask(true); // isCancelled is true.          
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Both your response and tomRedox suggest nearly the same thing. I implemented the cancelation token structure, but it doesn't seem to cut it. It seems like cts.Cancel() doesn't throw an exception. The measurements() method is momentarily interupted, it seems, but then goes on.

Comment: It is not even momentarily interupted, it just keeps rolling.

Comment: `await Task.Delay(120000, token)` ?
and if that doesn't throw an exception then follow the Delay statement with `if (token.IsCancellationRequested) token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();`